# How can i seperate TCL commands to different bathces on C#?

Tags: c#, batch-file, tcl

I'm trying to run tcl commands on C# to get datas from hardware manager. 
My problem is obligation of using a batch that includes “all” TCL commands in each "for cycle". Also in each step i’m calling settings64.bat too. This is time consuming.

My aim is to use some configuration commands before "for cycle" and use a trig command in each "for cycle";

```
# configuration commands
open_hw 
connect_hw_server ----
current_hw_target ----
set_property ----
open_hw_target
set_property ----
set_property ----
current_hw_device ----
refresh_hw_device ----
for
    # trigger commands
    run_hw_ila hw_ila_1
    wait_on_hw_ila hw_ila_1
    display_hw_ila_data [upload_hw_ila_data hw_ila_1]
    write_hw_ila_data waveform.zip -force
end for
```

However i can't split these TCL commands beacuse once a batch completes its task, it forgets the configuration that already had been sent.

How can i seperate these commands to different bathces ? Another approach is accepted.

Comment: I've tried to show what you wrote as code (hint: indent by 4 spaces does it) add some meaningful indentation and mark things as comments that look like they might be. I still don't understand exactly what you're trying to do though; it doesn't look close to any kind of conventional Tcl code as yet, so I can't guess from that.

Comment: And sometimes stuff is just plain old time consuming.